# Weird behaviour from S1J-13-F Diode

Tags: voltage, diodes, voltage-divider

I have the following circuit in which I expect a 1.1 V voltage ([datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/115/ds16003-83672.pdf))across the diode but I am measuring 6.18 V. This voltage is output no matter what way around I have the diode, consistently & I have swapped it out for another which does the same thing.

It's a 1 M resistor.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Is your 12V actually 12V AC and is your meter measuring AC?

Comment: 12.2V straight from a Lipo

Comment: Given the current your letting through the diode (12uA), I would expect about 0.7V drop instead of 1.1V (from figure 2 on datasheet). Still different from 6.6V. It would only drop 1.1V at 4A.

Comment: Can you add a photo of your test setup including multimeter settings? I'd just like to check for silly stuff. By the way, there's a schematic button on the editor toolbar ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not expect 1.1V at only ~11uA, more like 0.5V (simulation says 444mV).

If it has 6V across it when forward biased, it's either blown up or will be within milliseconds. You might be able to see evidence on the surface like a hole. Moderate overloads typically make a diode fail shorted, but Lipo battery has sufficient current capability to cause a small explosion most likely.

Or perhaps the parts are counterfeits and are bereft of internal die.

Presumably it also measures 6V when the erstwhile (or never-was) diode is entirely removed, which indicates your meter has rather low input resistance (maybe a really cheap one?).

Comment: Thanks, all parts from RS so I can only presume I'm blowing it up rather unspectacularly. I'll go find some zener diodes that do have a reverse voltage of something in the 6V region instead.

Comment: Another possibility is that it is actually a bipolar TVS. Even the best disties make mistakes when repackaging parts. In that case, it wouldn't typically have a polarity marking and it certainly wouldn't be marked the same as the proper part.